# Using other classes from other projects in my current JavaFX project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I've created a Node and `LinkedList` classes in the project `DataStructures` (which is a normal Java project).

Now, I want to use these two classes in my `DS_Lab_FX` JavaFX project.

[image]

I've tried to add the project (`DataStructures`) using these methods:

1. Build path -> Projects -> Add `DataStructures` project to module path.

But if I try to use the linked list, it gives this error:

[image]

I added `requires DataStructures;` to `module-info.java`. It compiled find, but it gives this runtime error:

[image]

2. Build path -> Projects -> Add `DataStructures` projects to class path this time.

Similar to above result, it says that the linked list is not accessible. So I added `requires DataStructures` to `module-info.java` file, but it says that `DataStructures` cannot resolve to a module.

[image]

[image]

3. Build path -> Libraries -> Add class folder (`DataStructures`) to module path.

But it says that the import linkedlist cannot be resolved:

[image]

4. Build path -> Libraries -> Add class folder (`DataStructures`) to class path.

And here shows the same error as method number 3.

**Why it's not working? And how can I fix this issue?**

Note: I'm using Eclipse 2023-03

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them has worked"? You haven't shown anything showing it not working. No error messages. No compiler errors. No config dialogs. No source indicating your data structures are declared correctly.

Comment: Does the `DS_Lab_FX` project have a `module-info.java` file? If yes, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on the project folder and choosing _Configure_) or add a `module-info.java` file to your `DataStructures` project, [in the `DS_Lab_FX` project's `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules) and make sure the `DataStructures` project has been added to the _Modulepath_, not to the _Classpath_.

Comment: Related discussion: [JavaFX complex project architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77412187/javafx-complex-project-architecture/77413555#77413555).  Provides general background info and not a specific solution to your question.

Comment: I've edited the post above and added more information about the errors I got...

Comment: @howlger I didn't quite get it, do you mean that I should add a module-info.java file to DataStructures project itself?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System

Comment: @howlger Also, I tried to delete the module-info.java file, it compiles fine, but it gives this runtime error: 
Error: Could not find or load main class application.MainWindow
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Comment: Your IDE is offering you ways to fix you modularization problem. See the green-arrow in your screen shot.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application` means that JavaFX classes cannot be found.  When you delete `module-info.java` from your project, then you need to add JavaFX to the module path explicitly (JavaFX can also be loaded from the classpath, but that has other pitfalls and is not recommended).  If you wish to use JavaFX in a non-modular project from Eclipse, then apply one of the *non-modular* options from the [JavaFX and Eclipse](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) section of the getting started instructions at openjfx.io.

Comment: Creating a reusable software library is a bit more complex than just adding classes to your project.  It is certainly possible and a good thing to do in some cases.  However, as you are having quite a few difficulties here, consider if what you are doing is worth the effort.  Instead of having the data structure code in a separate project, you could just copy the source code into your DS_Lab_FX project, compile and run your application as you were doing before, and get on with other tasks.  You can always refactor later once you better understand modularization.

Comment: Does deleting the run configuration in _Run > Run Configurations..._ after moving things between classpath and modulepath help. In general, when you have a `module-info.java` file, then you use [JPMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) and all dependencies have to be modules on the modulepath each module requires a `requires ...;` statement in the `module-info.java` file. When using JPMS, then nothing from the classpath is visible. In contrast, without a `module-info.java` everything from the classpath and modulepath can be used.